# How do I jump from one loop to another?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So I'm trying to make a loop that does something and then when it is finished set a var to false then move to the next loop (or otherwise exit and end the loop). Code:

```
var loop = true;

while (loop = true)
{
  console.log("whatevers");
  loop = false;
}
while (loop = false)
{
  console.log("meh");
  //continue endProgram;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is just assignment, where `==` or `===` is for comparisons. Assignment of a variable is evaluated as the expression after the assignment (*see @Oka comment*). For example: (`loop = true` => `true` while `loop = false` => `false`) Use `==` or `===` instead:

```
var loop = true;

while (loop == true)
{
  console.log("whatevers");
  loop = false;
}
while (loop == false)
{
  console.log("meh");
  //continue endProgram;
}
```

Comment: Ah that was an easy fix. Thank you!

Comment: Assignment expressions are evaluated as the LHS _after_ assignment. They are not always `true`. :: `if ((a = 0)) { console.log('Does not happen.') }` The problem is that `while (loop = false)` guarantees the loop will never run, since `loop` has just been assigned, and evaluates to, `false`.

Comment: @Oka Thanks, I didn't know that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way 
-------------------------------------------------------------------

var loop = true;

while (loop)
{
  console.log("whatevers");
  loop = false;
}
while (!loop)
{
  console.log("meh");
  //continue endProgram;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while(loop) is the same with while(loop == true )..but loop = true means that you set variable loop equal to true.So try this:

```
var loop = true;

while (loop)
{
console.log("whatevers");
loop = false;
}
while (!loop)
{
console.log("meh");
}
```